# SSH on Debian repeatedly requiring passphrase

Tags: ssh, debian

I am moving servers from Centos to Debian, mostly going well but one thing that is odd is that when connecting over SFTP I keep being re-asked for my SSH passphrase.

So I login and am asked as usual, but if I do something like move out of the original directory or try to write a file I am asked again for the passphrase. It seems like I'm asked once per type of operation so it's not like I am asked every time I do something. However if I open a project that had a lot of windows left open, I am asked for every open file window.

I have never come across this until moving to Debian so is this normal? Can I change this behaviour? I don't want my machine to save the passphrase by the way, I am happy using it once per login.

This has been happening in Coda 2 and Nova, possibly an issue with those editors but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Definitely not normal. Could it be that your commands are aliased to sudo operations?

Comment: I'm not using sudo at all, how would I find that out?

Comment: By the way this is happening on two separate servers.